# Pairs of isometries that jointly fix a set.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $E$ be a Euclidean space, and let $X, Y\subseteq E$ be two disjoint subsets.

Suppose that there exist isometries $i$ and $j$ such that $i(X)\cap j(Y)=\emptyset$ and $i(X)\cup j(Y)=X\cup Y$. Does it follow that there's an isometry fixing $X\cup Y$, mapping $X$ to $i(X)$ and mapping $Y$ to $j(Y)$? (Hints and pointers welcome too.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Let $X$ be a tetrahedron such that the only isometry fixing $X$ is the identity. (For example, $X$ could have six different edge lengths.) Now let $i$ be some translation that moves $X$ far away, so that $i(X) \cap X = \emptyset$. Write $Y = i(X)$ and $j = i^{-1}$.

Then $X$ and $Y$ satisfy the conditions. However, $i$ is the only isometry mapping $X$ to $i(X)$, and $i(Y) \ne X = j(Y)$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this -- that's exactly right.

Comment: Your answer also helped me get clear on the question that I wanted to ask (although I wasn't able to formulate it!) Given the set up above, I think what I really want to know is whether you could find a single isometry that *either* maps $X$ to $i(X)$ and $Y$ to $j(Y)$ *or* maps $X$ to $j(Y)$ and $Y$ to $i(X)$. Your counterexample doesn't extend to this hypothesis: do you know if this is true or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can ask a new question.

Comment: OK, I created a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025562/pairs-of-isometries-that-jointly-fix-a-set-revised